# JQuery Validate individual fieldsets

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've developed a form with multiple fieldsets to represent steps in filling out the complete form.  The fieldsets are shown and hidden by button click (one on each fieldset) but I want to validate each fieldset before the next is shown.

I'm new to JQuery and I'm having a bit of trouble.  I found this guide ( http://encosia.com/2009/11/24/asp-net-webforms-validation-groups-with-jquery-validation/) that  allows me to validate different fieldsets independently but my problem is how do I use that validation to control the showing and hiding of the relevent fieldsets.

I thought the way to do this would be to create a function from each click event for the buttons but I can't seem to call the validate function correctly.

I'm afraid I'm completely confused now!  Help!!

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across this example just before finding your question while googling something else, hoping this will help someone with the same problem:

https://djaodjin.com/blog/jquery-multi-step-validation.blog.html

Basically, apparently validation.js only validates the visible fields by default.

Here's the full example code, click through to the link to see the explanation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Multiple step form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #personal_information,
        #company_information{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST" id="myform">

                <fieldset id="account_information" class="">
                    <legend>Account information</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="conf_password" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Confirm password</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="conf_password" name="conf_password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary next">next</a></p>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset id="company_information" class="">
                    <legend>Account information</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="company" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Company</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="url" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Website url</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="Website url">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary next">next</a></p>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset id="personal_information" class="">
                    <legend>Personal information</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary" id="previous" >Previous</a></p>
                    <p><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="submit"></p>
                </fieldset>

            </form>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            // Custom method to validate username
            $.validator.addMethod("usernameRegex", function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/i.test(value);
            }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers");

            $(".next").click(function(){
                var form = $("#myform");
                form.validate({
                    errorElement: 'span',
                    errorClass: 'help-block',
                    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass("has-error");
                    },
                    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-error");
                    },
                    rules: {
                        username: {
                            required: true,
                            usernameRegex: true,
                            minlength: 6,
                        },
                        password : {
                            required: true,
                        },
                        conf_password : {
                            required: true,
                            equalTo: '#password',
                        },
                        company:{
                            required: true,
                        },
                        url:{
                            required: true,
                        },
                        name: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 3,
                        },
                        email: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 3,
                        },

                    },
                    messages: {
                        username: {
                            required: "Username required",
                        },
                        password : {
                            required: "Password required",
                        },
                        conf_password : {
                            required: "Password required",
                            equalTo: "Password don't match",
                        },
                        name: {
                            required: "Name required",
                        },
                        email: {
                            required: "Email required",
                        },
                    }
                });
                if (form.valid() === true){
                    if ($('#account_information').is(":visible")){
                        current_fs = $('#account_information');
                        next_fs = $('#company_information');
                    }else if($('#company_information').is(":visible")){
                        current_fs = $('#company_information');
                        next_fs = $('#personal_information');
                    }

                    next_fs.show(); 
                    current_fs.hide();
                }
            });

            $('#previous').click(function(){
                if($('#company_information').is(":visible")){
                    current_fs = $('#company_information');
                    next_fs = $('#account_information');
                }else if ($('#personal_information').is(":visible")){
                    current_fs = $('#personal_information');
                    next_fs = $('#company_information');
                }
                next_fs.show(); 
                current_fs.hide();
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom validation function for each fieldset and call it using the .keyup function. Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<div id="fieldset1">
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
</div>

<div id="fieldset2">
    <!--hidden using css-->
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#fieldset1 #fname').keyup(function () {
    // Runs every time your keystroke is released on this input
    if($(this).val() == 'Adam') {
        // Checks to see if the field's value is Adam. If it is, then it shows the next fieldset. Otherwise it hides it.
        $('#fieldset2').show();
    } else {
        $('#fieldset2').hide();
    }
}
```

This is obviously meant as a very simple example, but it illustrates what you will need to do in order to validate your form and modify the DOM based on user input.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  I see the logic in your answer but don't want to automatically show the next fieldset when data is entered into a field.  Can I tie the validation of a fieldset to a button?  e.g. create a function validateFS1() that returns true is the fieldset is valid.

Comment: Yes - you can use a button or a link - just insert some code that says onClick="validateFS1()" and use that function to show the next fieldset if validation returns true.

Answer (score 1):

Using [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin you can get around this by having multiple forms in the same page. You can then call:

> $('#myFormId').validate()

on the forms of interest one at the time.

Comment: Good to know, but I think there's an advantage to having all the fields in one form, probably easier to submit